# How to fix [BUG] Segmentation Fault occur while running rails app server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I have recently started using **rvm** to manage multiple ruby versions. I've set up a new project which will be using Ruby 2.1.6. I've created a new gemset to use with this version and have named it 'ruby2'. After explicitly setting ruby version as 2.1.6 and the new gemset, I tried running my rails app and encountered the following error

```
bin/rails s -p 3007
/home/knolly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@ruby2/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:67: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux] Brightbox

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0045 p:---- s:0131 b:0131 l:000130 d:000130 CFUNC  :initialize
c:0044 p:---- s:0129 b:0129 l:000128 d:000128 CFUNC  :new
c:0043 p:0099 s:0126 b:0124 l:000123 d:000123 METHOD /home/knolly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@ruby2/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:67
```

I found several posts on StackOverflow which suggested fixes like `gem pristine --all` but to no avail.

In the line :

```
/home/knolly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@ruby2/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:67: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux] Brightbox,
```

Rails seems to be using Ruby 1.9.3p551 (which I was using for my older applications) but rails console tells me it uses 2.1.6.

How to go about fixing this?

**Update**

I'm able to run the app when I do `bundle exec rails s -p 3007`. How do I run it using `bin/rails s`?

Comment: Regarding the ruby version, `rvm --default use 2.1.6` which change it at a whole for your user.

Answer (score 0):

In you app's root directory, create a file named `.ruby-version`, in that file just add `2.1.6`, now restart the terminal and enter in the app's directory. Your app will then by default use `ruby 2.1.6`.

Hope that helps!